# Copying files using shell Scripting

Tags: shell-script, redhat-enterprise-linux, tar

hellow guys,
please i need a script shell that can copy files from **server to another using SCP**. and put the files in **temperory folder** then copy from tmp to destination `/product/serv/nep/`

in case if the tmp is empty copy the zipped files from the backup folder `/product/backup_dumps` and **extract inside the destination** `/product/serv/nep/`. NB: **i need to compare the zipped files and copy the newer one. and extract the files inside the desitnation**. and that all

thanks you in advance :) ^_^

Comment: Super User is not a script writing service. We expect questions to demonstrate an attempt to solve the problem and evidence of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with test cases, concerning the comparison of newer files i have not really understood the meaning :

**TEST CASE 1 :**

```
## TEST Case if /tmpdir is empty, that means that /mediation from the remote server is empty
## Cleanup
rm -rf /product/serv/nep/*
rm -rf /tmpdir/*
## Creation
mkdir -p /product/backup_dumps/
mkdir /backup 
mkdir /backup/dir
touch /backup/dir/file2
touch /backup/dir/file2
tar -czvf backup.tar.gz /backup
cp backup.tar.gz /product/backup_dumps/
mkdir -p /product/serv/nep/
```

**TEST CASE 2 :**

```
## TEST Case if /tmpdir is not empty, that means that /mediation from the remote server is not empty
## Cleanup
rm -rf /tmpdir/*
## Creation
touch /tmpdir/filex
mkdir /tmpdir/dirX 
touch /tmpdir/dirX/filexx
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /tmpdir
scp -r <user>@<serverb>:/mediation/* /tmpdir
## Check whether /tmpdir is empty
if ls -1qA /tmpdir | grep -q .
then  
    ## If /tmpdir is not empty  then copy all the files without structure in /tmpdir to /product/serv/nep/
    find /tmpdir/ -type f | xargs -I {} cp {} /product/serv/nep/
else  
    ## If /tmp is empty, then copy the files in the compressed archive without structure to /product/serv/nep/
    list="$(tar -tvf /product/backup_dumps/backup.tar.gz)"
    echo "$list" 
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        char="$(echo "$line" | head -c 1)"
        ## Copy only files whithin the archive
        if [ $char != "d" ]
        then 
            file="$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $6}')"
            star -s '|*/||' -x -f /product/backup_dumps/backup.tar.gz $file -C /product/serv/nep/
        fi             
    done <<< "$list" 
fi
```